# Organization-wide email address - Use unverified email in sandbox

Tags: email, sandbox, organization-wide

I have created a workflow email alert to be sent from an organization wide email address which is verified only in the prod org.

I now need to create the same in dev sandbox and commit to git (We use Github and CircleCI for version control and deployment) so that it doesn't get overwritten from prod by the next deployment.

I tried creating a change set from prod to dev but it failed with the error message

`You must specify a verified Org Wide Email Address for this sender type.`

**Is there any way to override / work around this error message on sandboxes?**

I do not want the workflow rule itself to be functional in any of the sandboxes.

It is not an option to verify the email id on all sandboxes (8 of them) as the mailbox has several recipients who would not like to receive 8 verification emails from Salesforce.

Comment: If you don't want to use an org-wide address from production (that would be available in your sandbox after a refresh), I am pretty sure that this will not work. If you don't need your workflow rule to work in the sandbox, you might just change the email alert so the sender isn't an org-wide address.

Comment: Some options... Deactivate the workflows. Turn off email deliverability.

Comment: @georgw.
I want to use org-wide address from prod and I also need to be able to commit the workflow rule with the org-wide address to DEV branch in git (which would then try to deploy the workflow rule to a dev sandbox and fails as the org-wide address is not verified in the sandbox)

As it is now, I have go to and manually edit the from email address manually to the Org-wide address in prod after each deployment. This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've tried with email deliverability turned off, but I get the same error {You must specify a verified Org Wide Email Address for this sender type.} when I try to deploy the change set from prod into dev

Comment: Can we deploy the org wide email addresses through change sets ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be broken down into two parts:

1) How do I bypass a need to manually add/verify the production org wide email address in my sandboxes?

Unfortunately it does not appear to be possible. OrgWideEmailAddress is on the unsupported list.

http://www.asagarwal.com/767/metadata-components-that-needs-to-be-manually-deployed-in-salesforce

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=orgwide_email.htm&language=en_US

2) How do I prevent the sandbox from using this address via the workflows which I do not want to be active yet?

Again, it doesn't appear you can. If you want the workflows to be in the sandbox, they need a valid OrgWideEmailAddress to use, and if you give them a valid e-mail address, they will attempt to verify it.

Comment: thanks for that. It does appear impossible :( 

It would be interesting to see if anyone else using some kind of Continuous Integration set-up for deployment has faced the same problem and how they resolved it (other than having to manually set the org-wide email in prod after each deployment)

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have is to manually change the org-wide-email address in production after every deployment!

Comment: yes it appears so, unfortunately.  Either that or I should remove workflow rules from the list of components that I deploy using CircleCI and  deploy WF rules and email alerts using change sets.